# java: no suitable method found for setCellValue(java.time.LocalDateTime)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Entity

```
@Entity
public class ECard {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    //private int cardId;
    private String external_id;
    private String provider_id;
    private String full_name;
    private String login;
    private String name;
    private String sName;
    private String destination;
    private int commission_amount;
    private String status_id;
    private String amount_status_id;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = DATE_TIME_FORMAT)
    private LocalDateTime created_dt;
    private String provider_msg;

    public ECard() {
    }

    public ECard(//int cardId,
                 String external_id, String provider_id, String full_name, String login,
                 String name, String sName, String destination, int commission_amount, String status_id,
                 String amount_status_id, LocalDateTime created_dt, String provider_msg) {
       // this.cardId = cardId;
        this.external_id = external_id;
        this.provider_id = provider_id;
        this.full_name = full_name;
        this.login = login;
        this.name = name;
        this.sName = sName;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.commission_amount = commission_amount;
        this.status_id = status_id;
        this.amount_status_id = amount_status_id;
        this.created_dt = created_dt;
        this.provider_msg = provider_msg;
    }

    public ECard(Long id, //int cardId,
                 String external_id, String provider_id, String full_name, String login,
                 String name, String sName, String destination, int commission_amount, String status_id,
                 String amount_status_id, LocalDateTime created_dt, String provider_msg) {
        this.id = id;
        //this.cardId = cardId;
        this.external_id = external_id;
        this.provider_id = provider_id;
        this.full_name = full_name;
        this.login = login;
        this.name = name;
        this.sName = sName;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.commission_amount = commission_amount;
        this.status_id = status_id;
        this.amount_status_id = amount_status_id;
        this.created_dt = created_dt;
        this.provider_msg = provider_msg;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getExternal_id() {
        return external_id;
    }

    public String getProvider_id() {
        return provider_id;
    }

    public String getFull_name() {
        return full_name;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getsName() {
        return sName;
    }

    public String getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }

    public int getCommission_amount() {
        return commission_amount;
    }

    public String getStatus_id() {
        return status_id;
    }

    public String getAmount_status_id() {
        return amount_status_id;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreated_dt() {
        return created_dt;
    }

    public String getProvider_msg() {
        return provider_msg;
    }
```

WorkBook

```
private void saveExcel(List<ECard> list, String fileName) throws IOException {

        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("ECards");
        sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 6000);
        sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 4000);

        Row header = sheet.createRow(0);

        CellStyle headerStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        headerStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_BLUE.getIndex());
        headerStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

        XSSFFont font = ((XSSFWorkbook) workbook).createFont();
        font.setFontName("Arial");
        font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 16);
        font.setBold(true);
        headerStyle.setFont(font);

        Cell headerCell = header.createCell(0);
        headerCell.setCellValue("id");
        headerCell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);

        headerCell = header.createCell(1);
        headerCell.setCellValue("external_id");
        headerCell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);

        headerCell = header.createCell(2);
        headerCell.setCellValue("provider_id");
        headerCell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);

        headerCell = header.createCell(3);
        headerCell.setCellValue("full_name");
        headerCell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);

        headerCell = header.createCell(4);
        headerCell.setCellValue("login");
        headerCell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);

        headerCell = header.createCell(5);
        headerCell.setCellValue("name");
        headerCell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);

        headerCell = header.createCell(6);
        headerCell.setCellValue("sName");
        headerCell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);

        headerCell = header.createCell(7);
        headerCell.setCellValue("destination");
        headerCell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);

        headerCell = header.createCell(8);
        headerCell.setCellValue("commission_amount");
        headerCell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);

        headerCell = header.createCell(9);
        headerCell.setCellValue("status_id");
        headerCell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);

        headerCell = header.createCell(10);
        headerCell.setCellValue("amount_status_id");
        headerCell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);

        headerCell = header.createCell(11);
        headerCell.setCellValue("created_dt");
        headerCell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);

        headerCell = header.createCell(12);
        headerCell.setCellValue("provider_msg");
        headerCell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);

        CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        style.setWrapText(true);

        int ix_row=2;
        for (ECard eCard : list) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(ix_row);
            Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue(eCard.getId());
            cell.setCellStyle(style);

            cell = row.createCell(1);
            cell.setCellValue(eCard.getExternal_id());
            cell.setCellStyle(style);

            cell = row.createCell(2);
            cell.setCellValue(eCard.getProvider_id());
            cell.setCellStyle(style);

            cell = row.createCell(3);
            cell.setCellValue(eCard.getFull_name());
            cell.setCellStyle(style);

            cell = row.createCell(4);
            cell.setCellValue(eCard.getLogin());
            cell.setCellStyle(style);

            cell = row.createCell(5);
            cell.setCellValue(eCard.getName());
            cell.setCellStyle(style);

            cell = row.createCell(6);
            cell.setCellValue(eCard.getsName());
            cell.setCellStyle(style);

            cell = row.createCell(7);
            cell.setCellValue(eCard.getDestination());
            cell.setCellStyle(style);

            cell = row.createCell(8);
            cell.setCellValue(eCard.getCommission_amount());
            cell.setCellStyle(style);

            cell = row.createCell(9);
            cell.setCellValue(eCard.getStatus_id());
            cell.setCellStyle(style);

            cell = row.createCell(10);
            cell.setCellValue(eCard.getAmount_status_id());
            cell.setCellStyle(style);

            cell = row.createCell(11);
            cell.setCellValue(eCard.getCreated_dt());
            cell.setCellStyle(style);

//...
```

I want to get data in xlsx format from a database. In my database, the "created_dt" column is set in the format - timestamp without time zone. In Entity I put the format - LocalDateTime, but when I try to write "cell.setCellValue (eCard.getCreated_dt ());" The IDE tells me "Make" getCreated_dt "return boolean". But this is not correct? Can't find the right answer.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html), it has support for LocalDateTime objects. Check the specific documentation of the version of Apache POI you have. You can also check quickly by writing `cell.setCellValue` and checking what options the IDE brings up.

Comment: @Jetto Martínez I looked in the documentation, thanks for prompting. Found a suitable format - Date. Everything worked)
Can you make your hint as an answer? I will put it as "Solution"